# How to ignore_user_agent in Airbrake 5?

Tags: airbrake

We are migrating to Airbrake 5 and I'm wondering how to replace the functionality of the `ignore_user_agent` configuration.  I know we have to check in an `add_filter` block, but not sure what/where to check?

Does anyone have an example of replacing the ignore_user_agent configuration option in Airbrake 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be easy (assuming [this fix](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/pull/10) is merged in and the new gem is published):

```
Airbrake.add_filter do |notice|
  notice.ignore! if notice[:context][:userAgent].match(/curl/)
end
```

In the meantime, you can use [the class add_filter API](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby#using-classes-for-building-filters).

From: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-ruby/issues/9

**EDIT:** the new gem was published.